# Can Bluemix environment be replicated on developer laptops?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Can Bluemix environment with Liberty be replicated on developer laptops for offline development? Will I be able to run Bluemix local with Openstack on a quad core i5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run Cloud Foundry in a VM on your laptop using [bosh-lite](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite). You could also install the [open source Liberty buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack) into this local CF with the [buildpack dependencies cached](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack/blob/master/docs/installation.md) giving you an environment that could work offline.

The Bluemix services will not be available to you though, if you are offline, so the answer really depends on what services you need. You could reasonably set up some kind of local database but many of the services would just be unavailable.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a Bluemix instance with Liberty build-pack and a Postgre SQL DB. The cloud foundry instance should work for us. I'll update the thread after I try it. Thanks for the caching information. Should have been obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exact your requirement is. IBM Liberty profile can be setup with Eclipse and you can create a server in local to test your java/JEE code. This is very simple, you need to install liberty plugin in Eclipse and create a server. See documentations in IBM web site.

Answer (score 0):

See this url if it helps.. you can integrate BlueMix server to your Ecplise IDE
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/eclipsetools/eclipsetools.html